# Horizontal list to vertical

Tags: html, css

Why is the list of this message is in admin dashboard is horizontal but in other pages it is vertical?

```
.user-list{
display:inline;
}
.users header,
.users-list a{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
padding-bottom: 20px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? you code isn't enough to determinate where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Flexboxes are rows by default. To make them display as a column, add the property `flex-direction: column` or `flex-direction: column-reverse`.

Comment: Do i need to add this in user-list? when i add this in user-list there is no changes.

Comment: @Unwellee you would add it to the element which has `display:flex`, which in your case appears to be .users-list a. If you post the HTML connected to this CSS it would be easier to tell for sure.